# How do I set up the visual studio code launch.json file to debug F#?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, ionide

How do I set up the debugger in launch.json?

Currently, I have

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // Name of configuration
            // Appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
            "name": "Launch Lukecxu",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "/Users/lukexu/lukecxu",
            "type": "node",
            // Automatically stop program after launch.
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}" 
        }
    ]
}
```

I found some of this online but it's not working. It said I should have "type" as mono but when I set it has mono it said type not supported.

For my system settings I did brew install mono and I also have ionide installed.

Right now I can't click the gutter to set any break points and when I hit F5 it says `"Cannot launch program '/Users/lukexu/lukecxu'; configuring source maps might help."`

Is there a tutorial to set up F# debugger in VSCode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you need to install [mono debug extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.mono-debug)

After you've installed extension following configuration should work:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            // optional "preLaunchTask": "Build" - some way of building your application.
            "externalConsole": true, 
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "mono",
            // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/myapp/myapp.exe",
            "stopOnEntry": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "mono",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 55555
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: how would you achieve this for windows system

Comment: @GurbakhshishSingh its a work in progress: https://github.com/ionide/ionide-vscode-fsharp/pull/344

Comment: For me it works fine with some changes due to updated json rules except for breakpoints they never occur any idea why? @Kurren